# Why so differently when i import "org.mybatis.spring.boot" with maven? One has "org.apache.ibatis" and the othe one has no

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, mybatis, ibatis

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.fk</groupId>
    <artifactId>BootChecker</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.16.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
            <artifactId>druid-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Maven parent version of springboot is 2.1.16.RELEASE.
[pic1--](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXDl9.png)
[pic2--](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAIRk.png)
These two picture are showing the differentias.
I had imported the same dependence:

```
       <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
   <version>1.3.2</version>
```

1st pic is the correct config when i used the annotation @select to fill sql, because there is package "org.apache.ibatis" in repository.
In 2nd pic i can't use the annotation @select.

I have no idea now, thanks...

Comment: It worked when i clean caches of my maven repository those were failed to download,and restart idea.

Comment: Take a deep look here: https://blog.soebes.de/blog/2018/10/13/maven-artifact-checksums-what/

Comment: Ok.Thanks for your help.